# Android - I'm using countdown, If Else is not executing up to the end

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I've got a `private int counter` inside my class and I initialized it as `counter = 3;`inside my OnCreate().

This is my countdown codes inside my OnCreate:

`new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {`

```
         public void onTick(long msUntilFinished) {
             if (counter==3){
                 Toast.makeText(StartSingle.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 counter--;
             }else if (counter==2){
                 Toast.makeText(StartSingle.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 counter--;
             }else if (counter==1){
                 Toast.makeText(StartSingle.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 counter--;
             }else if (counter==0){
                 Toast.makeText(StartSingle.this, "Go!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnTick will be called at 2000, 1000, 0. At this time your counter = 1. It will not be 0.
You initial value for counter should be 2 perhaps.